# MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Select to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a edit form to edit data from database by id. I tried this:

```
    import React, {FormEvent, useEffect, useState} from "react";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import {
      TicketFullDTO,
      TicketStatusTypesDTO,
    } from "../../service/support/types";
    import {
      getTicket,
      getTicketStatusTypes,
      updateTicket,
    } from "../../service/support";
    import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
    import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    import { FormControl } from "@mui/material";
    import { Moment } from "moment";
    import { RouteParams } from "../../service/utils";
       
    export default function TicketProfile(props: any) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      let history = useHistory();
      let requestParams = useParams<RouteParams>();

      const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");
      const [submitDate, setSubmitDate] = useState<Moment | null>(null);
      const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
    
      const formSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);

        updateTicket(requestParams.id, data)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(data.title);
            history.replace("/support");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
    
      const [ticketCategoriesList, setTicketCategoriesList] = useState<
        TicketCategoryTypesDTO[]
      >([]);
      const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
            
      const getSingleTicket = async () => {
        getTicket(requestParams.id)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            setTicket(data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      const [ticketStatusList, setTicketStatusList] = useState<
        TicketStatusTypesDTO[]
      >([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ticketStatusData();
        getSingleTicket();
      }, []);
    
      const ticketStatusData = async () => {
        getTicketStatusTypes()
          .then((resp) => {
            setTicketStatusList(resp.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <Container>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>

                          .........

                          <TextField
                            value={ticket?.title}
                            id="title"                                             
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                              setTicket({ ...ticket, title: value });
                            }}
                          />

                          .........

                          <FormControl>
                            <TextField
                              label="Submit Date"
                              id="submit-date"
                              type="date"
                              defaultValue={ticket?.submitDate}                             
                              //@ts-ignore
                              onInput={(e) => setSubmitDate(e.target.value)}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                       
                          ..........

                            <Select
                              labelId="status-label"
                              id="status-helper"
                              value={ticket?.status}
                              onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
                              required
                            >
                              {ticketStatusList.map((element) => (
                                <MenuItem value={element.code}>
                                  {element.name}
                                </MenuItem>
                              ))}
                            </Select>
                          </FormControl>

                         ...........
                      
                          <Button
                            type="submit"
                          >
                            Update Ticket
                          </Button>                       
    
        </Container>
      );
    }


.....


export async function updateTicket(
    id: string,
    data: TicketFullDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketFullDTO>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketFullDTO>(
      `${baseUrl}/management/support/tickets/ticket/${id}`,
      {
        data,
      }
  );
}

export interface TicketFullDTO {
    id?: number,
    title?: string,
    status?: string,
    submitDate?: Moment | null
}
```

I get error:

`MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Select to be controlled. Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Select element for the lifetime of the component. The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not` undefined`.`

The value for `Select` should be selected using the value `ticket?.status` when list `ticketStatusList` But the data object is not running before rendering the UI content and the value into Select dropdown is not selected.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a default value to the ticket state, right now you have it as

```
const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketFullDTO>();
```

But at the very least, make it a blank `TicketFullDTO` or `null`

Comment: That doesn't help as null is the same as "empty" = uncontrolled which throws the same error.